# Spring Many to Many Association DTO Conversion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a standard many to many relationship in Spring with persistence using Hibernate. Constructors and setters left out for brevity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "as")
   private Set<B> bs;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "bs")
public class B {

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(
           name = "b_a",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   )
   private Set<A> as = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I also have DTOs for each of these classes and I have static methods to transfer between them. Due to the many-to-many relationship, I need to implement a form of state tracker to stop the program getting caught in infinite recursion.

```
public final class DTOEntityMapper {

    private static class StateHolder {
        private List<Object> alreadySeenObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        void addObject(Object o){
            alreadySeenObjects.add(o);
        }

        boolean contains(Object o){
            return alreadySeenObjects.contains(o);
        }
    }

    public static BDTO fromBToDTO(B b) {
        return fromBToDTO(b, new StateHolder());
    }

    private static BDTO fromBToDTO(B b, StateHolder state) {
       state.addObject(b);
       return BDTO.builder()
            .withAs(b.getAs().stream().filter(item -> !state.contains(item)).map(e -> fromAToDTO(e, state)).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
            .build();
    }
}

    // Note: fromAToDTO does same thing.
```

However when I try and test I get an assertion failure:

```
   @Test
   public void convertFromBToBDTO() {

    A a = new A("a");
    B b = new B("b");

    b.setAs(ImmutableSet.of(a));
    a.setBs(ImmutableSet.of(b));

    aDTO ADTO = new ADTO("a");
    bDTO BDTO = new BDTO("b");

    bDTO.setAs(ImmutableSet.of(aDTO));
    aDTO.setBs(ImmutableSet.of(bDTO));

    BDTO expected = bDTO;

    assertThat(DTOEntityMapper.fromBToDTO(b)).isEqualTo(expected);
}

Actual: BDTO{as=[ADTO{bs=}]}
Expected: BDTO{as=[ADTO{bs=b1}]}
```

Basically I am confused with how I deal with many-to-many relationships when converting between the data model and DTOs. Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: b.setAs(ImmutableSet.of(a1)); where is `a1` ?

Comment: I have updated this ^

Comment: Can you share ADTO and BDTO class also

Comment: The DTO classes are just POJOs with getters and a builder.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Test failure, see the assertion

Comment: Add them  also to find out the problem

Comment: I have shown the failed test